# looking for a const/non const element in a std::set in C++

Tags: c++11, containers

If I have a `std::set<unsigned> my_set` and I want to find if an element `unsigned a` belongs to my set.
Can I perform `auto it=my_set.find(a)` and then `if(it != my_set.end()` or the element a should be **const** (i.e. `const unsigned a`)?

Another question, when do I have to use `.cend()` instead of `.end()` and viceversa with a `std::set`?

Comment: Yes, you can perform `auto it=my_set.find(a)` and then `if(it != my_set.end()`. Yes, the element pointed to by `it` is `const`. It's not clear why you believe these two outcomes to be mutually exclusive, or even related at all. It's possible I don't understand the question.

Comment: For `std::set`, `iterator` and `const_iterator` behave the same, and in fact are usually the same type. `end()` vs `cend` won't make a difference. `std::set` provides both mostly so that all containers present a uniform interface.